# Get common data from Springboot AOP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop

I have a number of class where the first thing I have to do in the methods is retrieve the value of a variable from an external system.

```
class One {

  ExternalService externalService;
  public void method1() {
    var field = externalService.getValue();
    // do something with field
  }
}

class Two{

  ExternalService externalService;
  public void method2() {
    var field = externalService.getValue();
    // do something with field
  }
}
```

I think this functionality could extract it to an aspect and get the value of field. I have seen that you could make use of @Around. But my doubt is that once the field value is retrieved in the aspect, how do I return it to method1, method2 so that these methods can use the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not highlighted if its webapp/standalone app, I am going with webapp and my understanding.

**Way 1:**.

You can take help of spring bean lifecycle and do a common call to external service in `@PostConstruct` method. You can also explore other bean lifecycle callbacks for this purpose.

**Way 2:**.

There can be another way to do the same thing.
You can use spring bean scopes to wire such information based on your use case.

eg: is the data going to be unique per request then you can store data in request scope

else `session` or `application` scope are also available scopes.

Credits for this brilliant idea to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41774566/1811348

Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

**Way 3:**

Also instead of aspect you can also use filters, interceptors for same thing.
Here you can do it by:

a. create and set a threadlocal for per request bases. OR
b. add data to request attributes.

With aspects unfortunately its not possible
ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72277110/1811348